# Where are my TIME_WAITs on Mac OS X?

Tags: mac-osx, tcp, tcpip, socket, netstat

### No `TIME_WAIT`s on Mac OS X

Normally, when a TCP connection is closed, the socket on the side where `close()` is called first is left in the `TIME_WAIT` state.

When one of the peers is a Mac OS X (Lion) machine, no `TIME_WAIT` is listed by `netstat -an` on the Mac if `close()` is called first on the Mac side. However, it seems that the socket *is* actually in `TIME_WAIT` state, because trying to call `listen()` again (without using the socket option `SO_REUSEADDR`) causes `listen()` to fail.

Waiting for 2*MSL (Maximum Segment Lifetime which is 15 seconds on Mac OS X Lion as reported by `sysctl net.inet.tcp.msl`) clears the `TIME_WAIT` state, and `listen()` can be called again without error.

Why can't I see the socket in `TIME_WAIT`?

### Testing

Here are two simple test programs in Python.

**Server**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket

HOST = ''
PORT = 50007
l = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
l.bind((HOST, PORT))
l.listen(1)
print("Listening on %d" % PORT)
(s, _) = l.accept()
print("Connected")
raw_input("Press <enter> to close...")
l.close()
s.close()
print("Closed")
```

**Client**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
import sys

HOST = sys.argv[1]
PORT = 50007

print("Opening connection to server")
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
raw_input("Press <enter> to close...")
s.close()
print("Closed")
```

When running both the server and the client on two different Linux machines, the peer that press `<enter>` to call `close()` first gets a `TIME_WAIT` as expected:

```
$ ./server-timewait.py 
Listening on 50007
Connected
Press <enter> to close...
Closed
$ netstat -an | grep 50007
tcp        0      0 172.16.185.219:50007    172.16.185.42:49818     TIME_WAIT  
$
```

When one of the peers is a Mac (running OS X Lion) I never see a `TIME_WAIT` when running `netstat -an | grep 50007` after closing first on the Mac.

Comment: Good question. Seeing the same thing myself, and not seeing any options to netstat to include them…

Comment: FWIW, `sudo lsof -i -P` does not show TIME_WAIT status for processes that have already exited either.

Comment: @natevw Happy to know I am not alone. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This [bug report](http://www.openradar.me/22975100) claims that the problem is in the netstat [implementation](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/network_cmds/network_cmds-481.20.1/netstat.tproj/). The code attached to the bug report shows sockets in TIME_WAIT state correctly. You need to remove the following lines

```
if (lip == INADDR_LOCALHOST ||
  lip == INADDR_ANY
  ) { continue; }
```

to make it show sockets bound to localhost.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but someone maybe able to dig out more from this.

`tcpdump -i lo0 -vv port 50007`

```
## Press Enter at the server window

# Server send a FIN (note the flag)
23:33:04.283768 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 4134, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52, bad cksum 0 (->2c9c)!)
    localhost.50007 > localhost.56030: Flags [F.], cksum 0xfe28 (incorrect -> 0xeff9), seq 1, ack 1, win 9186, options [nop,nop,TS val 432165676 ecr 432157913], length 0

# Client send back ACK
23:33:04.283803 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 44906, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52, bad cksum 0 (->8d57)!)
    localhost.56030 > localhost.50007: Flags [.], cksum 0xfe28 (incorrect -> 0xd1a6), seq 1, ack 2, win 9186, options [nop,nop,TS val 432165676 ecr 432165676], length 0

# Server confirm the ACK is received
23:33:04.283812 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 18284, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52, bad cksum 0 (->f555)!)
    localhost.50007 > localhost.56030: Flags [.], cksum 0xfe28 (incorrect -> 0xd1a6), seq 2, ack 1, win 9186, options [nop,nop,TS val 432165676 ecr 432165676], length 0

## After this point, the server process is actually exit but client still running.
## It's strange that re-run server script gives "OSError: [Errno 48] Address already in use"
## and netstat shows this connection is in CLOSE_WAIT status

## Press Enter at the client window

# Client send a FIN to server
23:33:09.731728 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 51478, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52, bad cksum 0 (->73ab)!)
    localhost.56030 > localhost.50007: Flags [F.], cksum 0xfe28 (incorrect -> 0xbcb6), seq 1, ack 2, win 9186, options [nop,nop,TS val 432171035 ecr 432165676], length 0

# WTH!? Who send back this packet? The server process is closed!
23:33:09.731764 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 18754, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52, bad cksum 0 (->f37f)!)
    localhost.50007 > localhost.56030: Flags [.], cksum 0xfe28 (incorrect -> 0xa7c7), seq 2, ack 2, win 9186, options [nop,nop,TS val 432171035 ecr 432171035], length 0
```

Comment: "WTH!? Who send back this packet? The server process is closed!"

It seems to be sent by the server which is in TIME_WAIT state,because it is the part sending the first FIN. Even though the server process was terminated, TCP stack mantains state of the connection to send the last ACK.